# Multiple webpack bundles with browserslist and babel preset-env

Tags: webpack-4, babel-preset-env

- I am bundling using Webpack 4.
- I have multiple Webpack configurations exported in `webpack.config.js`.
- First configuration is to bundle lient code targeting browsers.
- Second configuration is to bundle server code targeting node.
- I am specifying these browsers and node targets using browserslist in `package.json`.

I need to specify different browserslists for client and server bundles, but I only have one browserslist key in `package.json`.

How can I specify different browserslists using package.json?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `package.json`. If you create a file called `.browserslistrc` or `browserslist` at the root of your project, you can use a different configuration.

```sh
# Any general config goes at the very top, above any section headers
# ...

# Put section headers in [brackets]

[node]
supports es6-modules

[web]
>1% and not dead
```

Then call `webpack` and set `BROWSERSLIST_ENV`:

```sh
BROWSERSLIST_ENV=dev webpack -c webpack.dev.js # Build development
BROWSERSLIST_ENV=prod webpack -c webpack.prod.js # Build production
```

Your `webpack` command may be different depending on your configuration.